# What's the correct way of defining style attributes in Quill Parchment

Tags: quill, parchment

I've tried all the examples in the Parchment docs, but none of them work correctly. For example, using the following code from the documentation...

```
import Parchment from 'parchment';

let Align = new Parchment.Attributor.Style('align', 'text-align', {
  whitelist: ['right', 'center', 'justify']   // Having no value implies left align
});
Parchment.register(Align);

let node = document.createElement('div');
Align.add(node, 'right');
console.log(node.outerHTML);
```

The docs state that this will print `<div class="blot-align-right"></div>`, but I actually just get `<div></div>`.

I've checked what happens in the debugger. `Align.add()` calls `canAdd()`, which always returns false.

Can anyone provide a working example of using Parchment?

Comment: I've made some progress. Looks like you might also need to register a blot that represents the div, or attributes will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Parchment = Quill.import('parchment');

let Align = new Parchment.Attributor.Style('align', 'text-align', {
  whitelist: ['right', 'center', 'justify']
});

Quill.register(Align);

let node = document.createElement('div');
Align.add(node, 'right');
console.log(node.outerHTML);
```